# How to get a customer ID from event object in stripe

Tags: php, yii2, stripe-payments

In my application, when a user signs up, a customer is created in `stripe`. A subscription is also created for that customer on trial basis. When that trial period ends, the customer is charged. I have a `web-hook` for events happening in stripe so whenever `charge.succeeded` occurs, I make some changes in my database. I need to retrieve the customer id form the event object that is `posted` from the stripe. and I am doing it like this:

```
$stripeCustomerId = $event->customer;
```

Now when I checked in stripe dashboard, everything is fine, customer status is changed from trialing to active, and the web-hook returns the object fine. But I am unable to get customer id from that object. What am I missing here? Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at the response object that stripe posts, it has `event->data->object->customer` hierarchy. so you can get the customer Id like this:

```
$body = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event_json = json_decode($body);
$event_json->data->object->customer;
```

cheers!