# How to get customer id from stripe event

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have set up a webhook where events sent from **stripe** are handled. I, however, have noticed that not all events share the same structure.

I am currently retrieving the customer this way:

```
$input = @file_get_contents("php://input");
$event_json = json_decode($input);

$customerId = $event_json->data->object->customer
```

After a day or two I found out that not all events contain the customer under `$event_json->data->object->customer`. Here is an example response:

```
{
  "object": {
    "id": "cus_Ac3Sx3Bn7cuvqB",
    "object": "customer",
    "account_balance": -3099,
    "created": 1494163341,
    "currency": "usd",
    "default_source": "card_1AGpL4ByNDe65wcFOfqQZGCc",
    "delinquent": false,
    "description": "John John",
    "discount": null,
    "email": "john.john@john.com",
    "livemode": false,
    "metadata": {
    },
    "shipping": null,
    "sources": {
      "object": "list",
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "card_1AGpL4ByNDe65wcFOfqQZGCc",
          "object": "card",
          "address_city": null,
          "address_country": null,
          "address_line1": null,
          "address_line1_check": null,
          "address_line2": null,
          "address_state": null,
          "address_zip": null,
          "address_zip_check": null,
          "brand": "Visa",
          "country": "US",
          "customer": "cus_Ac3Sx3Bn7cuvqB",
          "cvc_check": "pass",
          "dynamic_last4": null,
          "exp_month": 7,
          "exp_year": 2017,
          "fingerprint": "lI2tl3FOGKOG7PcZ",
          "funding": "credit",
          "last4": "4242",
          "metadata": {
          },
          "name": "John John",
          "tokenization_method": null
        }
      ],
      "has_more": false,
      "total_count": 1,
      "url": "/v1/customers/cus_Ac3Sx3Bn7cuvqB/sources"
    },
    "subscriptions": {
      "object": "list",
      "data": [
      ],
      "has_more": false,
      "total_count": 0,
      "url": "/v1/customers/cus_Ac3Sx3Bn7cuvqB/subscriptions"
    }
  }
}
```

What I am asking is where I can see an example of all possible event structures so that I can make sure my webhook doesn't return `Could not determine which URL to request: Stripe\Customer instance has invalid ID: (500 Internal Server Error)?`

Note: I did see this question - [How to get a customer ID from event object in stripe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43038150/how-to-get-a-customer-id-from-event-object-in-stripe) but there the only given way is `$event_json->data->object->customer`

Comment: It's `$event_json->object->sources->data[0]->customer`

Comment: In this specific example - it is, yes. It doesn't cover all event types, however.

Answer (score 2):

Stripe webhooks share the same structure as the API endpoints for the relevant objects.  In the example above, the `object` field is set to `customer`, so you can see the structure in the API docs at https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object .  If you go to https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/webhooks and add an endpoint, and choose "Select types to send", you can see all the types of webhooks that will be sent to you.

There are a lot of events where it doesn't really make sense to look for a `customer` on the event, so it would probably be useful to only subscribe to the event types you want.